# Python Relative Import in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, relative-import

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
 dir_1
 ├── functions.py
 └── dir_2
     └── code.ipynb
```

In, `code.ipynb`, I simply want to access a function inside `functions.py` and tried this:

```
from ..functions import some_function
```

I get the error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have checked a bunch of similar posts but not yet figured this out... I am running jupyter notebook from a `conda env` and my python version is `3.7.6`.

Comment: Where is the notebook situated in relation to the other files?

Comment: The notebook would be `code.py` in the example. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your notebook do:

```
import os, sys
dir2 = os.path.abspath('')
dir1 = os.path.dirname(dir2)
if not dir1 in sys.path: sys.path.append(dir1)
from functions import some_function
```

Answer (score 6):

The jupyter notebook starts with the current working directory in sys.path.
see [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path)

> ... the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

If your utility functions are in the parent directory, you could do:

```
import os, sys
parent_dir = os.path.abspath('..')
# the parent_dir could already be there if the kernel was not restarted,
# and we run this cell again
if parent_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(parent_dir)
from functions import some_function
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a structure like this:

```py
 dir_1
 ├── functions
 │   └──__init__.py  # contains some_function
 └── dir_2
     └── code.ipynb
```

We are simply inserting a relative path into `sys.path`:

```py
import sys

if ".." not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, "..")
from functions import some_function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')` and then try to import

Comment: Thanks! I really would like to avoid stating explicit paths though. Is there no way around this? Why am I getting the mentioned error?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: I believe the problem is due to your relative import. You might want to try something like python3 -m dir_2/code.py

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am running a jupyter notebook, and the whole point is that I want to use the relative path and avoid explicit paths.

Comment: To be able to use relative paths, you should be working in packages. 'In other words, the algorithm to resolve the module is based on the values of __name__ and __package__ variables.' In your case, you don't have a package so __package__ is none. You need to have __init__.py to make your directory a package. Two different solutions are here in a detailed manner: https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent/p2

Comment: Also, it is generally advised not to use relative paths as modules tend to move around a lot. So please also consider that